# Auto-hide taskbar in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, taskbar

I use the auto-hide taskbar feature and I have problems with Google Chrome when it is maximized: the taskbar will not pop up at mouse hover over the taskbar position (really annoying).

I know that Google admits it is a bug and it hasn't been fixed yet, and probably it will never be fixed.
My question is if you know a workaround to avoid this issue.

Comment: sometimes it happens and the taskbar still hide with chrome, in my case i to wait for the taskbar to behave normally or shut down chrome and remove the process in the task manager, or put a normal taskbar half an hour and I try after

Comment: None of the above worked for me, thus I resorted to:
1. Restoring Down
2. Dragging the window to the side of my screen so that 7 would make it occupy half.
3. Resizing the window over my full screen. There's practically no difference. Hope this helps.

Comment: I could only see the taskbar with the Windows key, or minimizing etc. Finally recycled Chrome and all appears well. I see posts all over the web for this going back years. There doesn't seem to be a real permanent solution anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply a theme to Google Chrome to fix it.

Comment: Any theme, or do you have an example of theme to provide?

Comment: any of https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en/themes/index.html

Comment: the window transparecy is the problem of chrome here, i think.

Comment: Thanks. I applied a theme and so far everything is OK. http://www.chromethemes.org/miscellaneous/sleek_and_sexy/
Daily vote limit reached :P (I'll give you later the vote, and will mark your answer as accepted)

Comment: I'm giving the ["Plain" theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plain/ajpcdipecmmhmhfchegpaflpjkmceiip?hl=en) a go, which is basically a "no-theme" (defaults to Google Chrome's native look).

Comment: I downvoted because this did not fix the problem for me (win7, 32bit).  Also, I don't think the other solutions are good, because they depend on the keyboard.  Based on track record I doubt Google will ever fix this - only solution I could come up with is good old Firefox!

Comment: It worked for me after restarting chrome on Win7, 64-bit

Answer (score 7):

You can temporarily force out the auto-hidden taskbar from cover by bringing up the Start menu.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to force the Windows Start menu to display, and with it, the taskbar will pop up.

Comment: It also works if you press the Windows key. Anyway this must be used every time the taskbar doesn't pop up.

Comment: Yes! The Windows button does exactly the same thing.

Comment: In Windows 8 this displays the Start screen instead of the taskbar.

Answer (score 5):

Try pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> twice.  It works for some.

Comment: This works as a temporary workaround.

Comment: This works.[​](http://google.com)

Comment: Not any more... :(

Answer (score 3):

Yes, to get the task bar back, ***Restore Down,*** or double click an empty place on top. Then minimize the window. Then *Restore* the window, then *Maxamize* it. :) It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, however, pressing the Window key is much easier, or any of the above shortcuts. My main problem is that I cannot see the GTalk notifications for example, nor the new emails (the envelope)....and I have to check it from time to time to see ... (+1 for your answer)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I guess Windows would work too :P

Comment: After reading and trying everything else, I was disappointed to see that the last option was so stupid and obviously not going to work. And then it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From a Google support thread [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3a0c6d2e6dd8f579&hl=en):

> I'm running Windows 7, 32 bit and had the same problem that the taskbar (on autohide) won't appear with Chrome maximized. I solved this by setting the Properties -> Compatibility -> Compatibility mode to "Windows Vista (Service Pack 2)" for chrome.exe.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this but still the same. After a few minutes the problem persists (I'm running Windows 7 64bit). +1

Comment: OK, thanks for your feedback Nicu.  Have you tried any of the other compatibility modes to see if they help?